# Kubernetes is not creating internet-facing AWS Classic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, nginx-ingress

as far as I get the ingress controller documentation, a simple creation of a Service and an Ingress without special annotations should create internet-facing load balancers, weirdly it is creating internal load balancers. So I added the annotation `service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false"` which is not working either. By the way, I am using NGINX as ingress controller, in the test cluster currently in version 0.8.21. Probably I should update it some time.

Here's my simple spec-file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "false"
  labels:
    external: "true"
    comp: ingress-nginx
    env: develop
  name: develop-api-external-ing
  namespace: develop
spec:
  rules:
    - host: api.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: api-external
              servicePort: 3000
            path: /
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - api.example.com
      secretName: api-tls
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: api
    env: develop
  name: api-external
  namespace: develop
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: api
    env: develop
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong, a service and a ingress should create a load balancer... but you should look at the documentation a bit more...

An ingress needs a NodePort service, yours is ClusterIP. So even if it created something it wouldn't work.

In your ingress you are using `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` meaning you want to override the default usage of the ingress and force it to register to the ingress-nginx.

So to make it work, change the type of your service, remove the ingress-class annotation.

Comment: Didn't work, sorry. Changed `ClusterIP` to `NodePort` and removed `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx`.

Comment: Actually it also doesn't make sense to me, why I should use a `NodePort`. This exposes my service, while originally the ingress controller should be exposed only.

Comment: The ingress will create a ressource in the provider (only used in cloud so don't know of this works in an on-prem conf), the LB. But this one don't know the pods and needs a target group of compute instances. That's why you need a nodeport service to make it work, this will open the port on the instances and allow communication between the lb and your apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup NLB ( Network load balancer) and provide the URL on ingress rule host values. You don't need to expose the underneath backend service either as NodePort or as another load balancer.